# Swapping 3Ware Raid Card - Best Procedure

Tags: raid, 3ware, raid-controller

We have a server running an old firmware version and driver (just took this position) on the 3Ware 9650SE Raid Controller... We have been having issues with the server and seemed to have narrowed it down to the Raid Card...

I will be replacing the Raid card with the same model of 3Ware 9650SE, however, the card ordered most likely will have newer firmware on it.

I managed to backup all the data to a very large drive.
My plan is to update the firmware/driver on the current setup (which is still booting) and verify that everything works..

Then throw in the new Raid Card, check the firmware version (not letting it post). And update to newest firmware if needed via Java management utility on the card?

Is this the best route?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a 9650SE-8i which broke. I called 3Ware and the lady who answered the phone informed me that the array configuration was stored on the drives and that plugging the old drives into a new (either identical or same line) card should just work.

Since the local stores no longer carried 9650SE's I got a 9750. I am happy to report that things indeed 'just worked'. I can't imagine that a different firmware on a new 9650SE will be different.

Having said that: Making a backup before doing anything is certainly the safest way. Even if for nothing else than peace of mind.

Comment: I know that the plural of anecdote isn't evidence, but this is also my experience.  You should be perfectly fine going from cards with one firmware revision to another, and you already have backups.  You should be good to go.

Comment: I can confirmed this worked, even swapping to card with newer firmware. I then updated to latest driver and firmware. Detected array and drives saw the controller just fine.

Answer (score 2):

That certainly seems reasonable. Just make sure to verify your backup and do some test restores to make sure things are good to go there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about forward compatibilty, but I would note that even though the configuration information is stored on the disk, that doesn't mean that arrays are backward compatible with a controller with older firmware on it.  I discovered that while testing three separate 9650se controllers to ensure interoperability.  The controller with the old firmware will not recognize the metadata on disk arrays formatted with the newer firmware.

Comment: That is more a comment than an answer.